# Python Class property not taking arguments properly

Tags: python, class, properties

This Class should accept an argument to the `Keys` property, but when I try `MyUserInstance.Keys('foo')`, it doesn't work.  Instead it says `TypeError: Keys() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.  How is it wrong?

```
# User
class User:
    def __init__(self,
            Username = 'New User',
            **kwargs):
        self.Username = Username
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    @property
    def Keys(self,collection):
        try:
            return {k:1 for k in db.UserPreferences.find_one({
                'Type':'VisibleKeys',
                'UserID':self._id,
                'CollectionName':collection})['Keys']}
        except:
            return None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User: "%s">' % self.Username
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keys is a bound property of an instance of your class. That means you must first have an instance.

```
user = User()
user.Keys = "foo"
```

Also get rid of the collection arg. Thats a getter. You can only define the arg on setters.

It looks like it really should be just a method. So actually, get rid of the property decorator and use:  user.keys("foo")

You can read about how to define getter, setter, and deleter here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Also python convention would normally reserve the uppercase for class names. It would be User.keys

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think I've put you down the wrong path.  I've edited the question for clarity.  Assume that I have already have an instance.  I just want to return a dictionary from my database using the `collection` as an argument.  Why does it tell me I have the wrong number of arguments when clearly, I don't?

Comment: Yes the capital naming made it look like the class. But the rest of the answer is still correct. You are using property wrong. They dont take args. Remove the property decorator and make it a normal method and it will work as you are using it.

Comment: Thanks so much and sorry for the confusion.